# ASP.NET 4 State Manegment

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I am working on an ASP.NEt 4 application and I discover a new collection availabe: the

> **ControlState**

I read some documentation that tell this collection, serve to store small information, also id the "old" ViewState is disable to performance needs.

My questions are:

1. Is possible to disable?
2. Where does they techically differ?

Comment: It's not. It's from 2.0 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.savecontrolstate(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of the control state is that it cannot be disabled. Basically if the designer added control state to a control this means that the control cannot possibly work without storing the information somewhere. If the control can be used without storing this additional data then the developer of the control should have stored the data in the ViewState. If you think about it the developer could still store data on the page if he added his own hidden field and the client code would not be able to disable it. The ControlState provides a way for the developer to use the existing infrastructure without worry that the client code could disable it.